# How to get data from Json Object using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm getting data as a json object

```
var data =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(data);
```

On data console I got this. I want to get key and its value .

```
 {lobby: {…}}
 lobby:
 8jmb9ca3s04c8el4j5sf0d:"AD8BJBkMKCBoYg_qAAAB"
 38cjllj78cx0lic58ujxou:"PX51X9z_M34_9BvtAAAD"
 ba8gs1y8779kmakdapxk1:"UowsBDCCsZSpojzPAAAA"
```

Comment: Can you share the exact log?

Comment: Note that `data` is already an object, so stringifying and parsing it are redundant. If you know the keys you want to access, just use the directly, eg: `data.lobby['ba8gs1y8779kmakdapxk1']`. If you don't know the keys, use `Object.keys` to retrieve them.

Comment: if i don't use stringyfy it gives me error Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: That's not a JSON, even the syntax highlighter does not understand it. after the second 'lobby' a graph parenthesis should open

Comment: @MuhammadAwais don't use `JSON.parse` either.

Answer (score 3):

1. Parse JSON to Object `var data =  JSON.parse(jsonData);`
2. Use `Object.keys(data);` to get all keys
3. Use `data.key` or `data['key']` to get key value.